# Autotools does not detect my architecture correctly. How to handle?

Tags: compiling, ffmpeg, automake, autoconf

I am trying to build the latest ffmpeg from the git repo. However, as you can see below, autotools does not detect correctly that **my box has 64-bit architecture (Ubuntu 12.04)**. Consequently, during the build, some x86 libs are required, but not present, and the build fails. How do I tackle this?

> mvitkov@mms:~/projects/ffmpeg/build$ ../ffmpeg/configure --enable-shared
>   output:
>   *install prefix            /usr/local
>
>   source path               /home/users/mvitkov/projects/ffmpeg/ffmpeg
>
>   C compiler                gcc
>
>   ARCH                      x86 (generic)*

On the other hand, autotools usually works fine:

> mvitkov@mms:~/projects/x264/build$ ../x264/configure --enable-static
>   output:
>   *platform:      X86_64*

Comment: I hope this is the correct SE for my question.

Comment: "ARCH=x86_64 ./configure" seems to work - everithing builds. However, configure still displays x86 (generic), so I'm leaving the question open.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to build a 64bit version of ffmpeg? Are you sure your compiler isn't making 64bit binaries by default anyway? If it's not, the usual thing to do is to edit your `CFLAGS`, `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`.

You'd probably use something like this:-

```
CFLAGS="-m64 -O3 -fPIC"  CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS" LDFLAGS="-melf_x86_64 -O3" ../ffmpeg/configure --enable-static
```

It's always worth checking the other options available in 'configure --help'.  ffmpeg has a LOT of optional dependencies, some of which you will probably want to enable.

The other way to target a specific architecture and platform is to use the `--host`, `--target` and `--build` configure flags. These are standard autotools flags. I always get them mixed up, but a concise explanation of them can be found [on linuxforums](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/explaining-build-host-target-509739/).